# only left X when stock is under 24

Tags: magento-1.9

Im using configurable products, and i'd like to show simple products' stock when it is under 24.

so i created new  for showing stock. 
and it works so well.... but the problem is, some specific products show its stock even though is over 24...

The simple products that show its stock more than 24, keep showing its stock even though i deleted and recreated configurable products, and un-associated and re-associated simple products.

i coded in 2 different ways. but neither of this works. plz help me

sol1)

```
<td class="only<?php echo $hidden_super_val=''.$productVal['info']['prod_id'].'_'.$att['attribute_id'].'';?>" >
  <div class="only">
                   <?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() == 1) :?>
     <?php if ($productVal['info']['qty'] <= 24): ?>
       <?php echo "ONLY LEFT" ?><br/ >
       <?php echo $productVal['info']['qty']; ?>
                                 <?php else: ?>
                                  <?php echo '' ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif;?>
  <?php endif;?>               
</td>
```

sol2)

```
<?php $kbstock = number_format(Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($assc_products)->getQty()); ?>    
<td class="only<?php echo $hidden_super_val=''.$productVal['info']['prod_id'].'_'.$att['attribute_id'].'';?>" >
                <div class="only">
                    <?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() == 1) :?>
                                  <?php if ($kbstock <= 24): ?>
                     <?php echo "ONLY LEFT" ?><br/ >
               <?php echo $$kbstock; ?>
                                 <?php else: ?>
                                <?php echo '' ?>
                 </div>
          <?php endif;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get all child products(simple) ids

```
$ids = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
        ->getChildrenIds($_product->getId());
```

after that you can load each simple product and get the Stock of it

```
foreach($ids as $id){
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
           ->loadByProduct($id);
}
```

you will get the stock of each simple product individually. Thanks :)